# checking if coupon code is valid

Tags: php-5.4, ajax, coupon, coupon-codes

I need to figure out a method to check whether a coupon code is valid or not and add this method to a boolean.  I have a few cases as to why:

1.`controller is offered a valid coupon code`

2.`controller is offered an invalid coupon code`

3.`controller is offered no coupon code and this will generate coupon code removal` functionality.

```
If(valid){
    coupon is added to order, ajax response (1) is prepared
}
elseif(!valid){
    ajax response (2) is prepared
}
else{
    coupon is removed from order, ajax response (3) is prepared
}
```

TLDR:  How do I check whether a coupon code is valid or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On custom controller add an action which is check current coupen is validate and and apply.

```
public function couponPostAction()
{
 $result=array();
if (!Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCount()) {
    $result['valid']=0;
    $result['message']='YOUR ERROR Message';

}

$couponCode = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code');
if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('remove') == 1) {
    $couponCode = '';
}
$oldCouponCode = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();

if (!strlen($couponCode) && !strlen($oldCouponCode)) {

 }

try {
    $codeLength = strlen($couponCode);
    $isCodeLengthValid = $codeLength && $codeLength <= Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart::COUPON_CODE_MAX_LENGTH;

    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setCouponCode($isCodeLengthValid ? $couponCode : '')
        ->collectTotals()
        ->save();

    if ($codeLength) {
        if ($isCodeLengthValid && $couponCode == Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getCouponCode()) {

        $result['valid']='success';
        $result['message']=$this->__('Coupon code "%s" was applied.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($couponCode));
        } else {
        $result['valid']='failed';
        $result['message']=$this->__('Coupon code "%s" is not valid.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($couponCode));

        }
    } else {

    $result['valid']='remove';
    $result['message']=$this->__('Coupon code was canceled.');

    }

} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
   $e->getMessage();
        $result['valid']='failed';
        $result['message']=$this->__('Cannot apply the coupon code');

} catch (Exception $e) {
        $result['valid']='failed';
        $result['message']=$this->__('Cannot apply the coupon code.');

    Mage::logException($e);

}

    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
}
```

In my code i have created action `couponPostAction` and this function is `return jSON data(message, valid)`. and you you have remove coupon then send an extra params  `remove`
$this->getRequest()->getParam('remove') which coupon from current cart